# Is there any technique to force a daemon thread to finish some task if User threads already finished their working?

Tags: java, multithreading

In my main program I am running 1 User Thread and all its child are daemon threads. Because of this when the user thread finished its working all daemon threads terminates as well. I am executing some code block in daemon threads that must be finished before thread termination.

Is it possible to wait for a particular block execution in daemon thread if user threads finished their working?

Comment: Have you tried `Thread.join()`?

Comment: If you have to wait for something in a thread to complete, why is it a daemon thread. I would make it a normal thread. There is no need to make background threads a daemon.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I am running some infinite loops in daemon threads. So if i try to stop the application in normal way it can't if i use User Thread. Still i need some part of code that started must be finished before daemon terminated.

Comment: You can tell the threads to shutdown gracefully with a flag because only they know when they are finished doing what they need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this different ways

1. Using Thread.join();
2. Using Observer-Observable pattern
3. Using CountDownLatch

Answer (score 1):

First, if one really needs some code block being run by a thread to finish executing, then that thread isn't really a daemon thread.

However, to accomplish what you ask, you can have your main thread wait for the daemon thread via [Thread#join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the CountDownLatch or Cyclic Barrier?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends from what you actually want to do:

1. You want to avoid a demon thread to be shut down while it's within a critical section. 
   Solution: the demon threads aquire a read lock while in this section and the User thread has to aquire the write lock before dying.
2. You have a rather independent code block to be excuted before shut down.
   Solution: Shut down hook

   Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
       public void run() { database.close(); }
   });
3. You want to gracefully shut down your threads. Solution: Use user threads. Interupt them to stop them. Use one of the named solutions to wait.

Bullet 1 in more detail:

It's based on [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html).

```
// Demon
Lock l = readWriteLock.getReadLock(); 
l.lock(); // Will wait here if WriteLock is requested
try {
    // access the resource protected by this lock
} finally {
    l.unlock();
}


// User
Lock l = readWriteLock.getWriteLock(); 
l.lock(); // Will wait here until all readLock are unlocked
// no need to unlock. Dys anyway
```